# Android : sync and map

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have just started with android ...

I have to develop an android application which should sync with data on webserver..

User adds some data using website, then data should be pulled and synced with data on android device...
I am not sure how to implement this...

Also I have to show map path only between two points (src,dest).. I have googled and it lloks like there is no built-in... only way is to use overlays and draw method.. is my understanding correct??

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to a server, there're several ways:

1. Your apps registers on the server and then server, knowing the IP, sends the info from time to time. The idea here is the server remembers the device IP, the application is listening on a port and the server connects from time to time to that port and sends info. In case the device gets another IP it needs to notify the server.
2. Your app asking the server whether there's new info from time to time
3. Using android sync API (sorry, don't know any details about it)

Comment: thanks... but can you please elaborate on option 1... how can web server notify android app??

Comment: @prolog_noob - added some details.